# How can I split a string using a regular expression, to the left of the matching string?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following sample text:

```
Performed by:

ID NUMBER:
XSOR-160491"
15632894,136259874,"TEXT:
Name: John    Age:80
[Lots of text spanning multiple lines with special characters, new lines and whitespaces]
XSOR-160491"
78452156,784569851,"TEXT:
Name: Sally    Age:31
[Lots of text spanning multiple lines with special characters, new lines and whitespaces]

ID NUMBER:
01236589,489456156878,"TEXT:
Name: Suraj    Age:56
[Lots of text spanning multiple lines with special characters, new lines and whitespaces]

00123795,,"TEXT:
Name: Shiloh    Age:12
[Lots of text spanning multiple lines with special characters, new lines and whitespaces]
```

And I'm trying to split it to the left of:
**ID NUMBER:

XSOR-160491"**
15632894,**136259874,**"TEXT:
where all the bolded text is optional (not present in every instance).

I created the following regex expression but it consumes the information I want to keep and doesn't necessarily account for all the bolded optional text.

```
re.split(r"[0-9]+,[0-9]+?,\"TEXT", test))
```

I tried adding lookahead with `?=`:

```
re.split(r"?=([0-9]+,[0-9]+?,\"TEXT)", test))
```

But that didn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Expected output is as follows:

```
ID NUMBER:
XSOR-160491"
15632894,136259874,"TEXT:
Name: John    Age:80
...
```

---

```
XSOR-160491"
78452156,784569851,"TEXT:
Name: Sally    Age:31 
...
```

---

```
ID NUMBER:
01236589,489456156878,"TEXT:
Name: Suraj    Age:56
...
```

---

```
00123795,,"TEXT:
Name: Shiloh    Age:12
...
```

Comment: I don't follow - what is your expected output?

Comment: what are you looking for after th split ??

Comment: @anubhava that doesn't seem to work since the text between each delimiter has a lot of whitespace, new lines and special characters.

Comment: You should understand that by putting `[Lots of text spanning multiple lines with special characters, new lines and whitespaces]` you have made your problem hard to understand for anyone to make an attempt to answer.

Comment: @anubhava The text varies too much and the only (semi) constants are what I've explicitly written above. These specific sections don't appear anywhere else and that's why I want to explicitly use them to split the text. The solution I have semi-woks but consumes the match.

Comment: Is there always an empty line before the split point?

Comment: @trincot no, the only constant seems to be 'NUMBER,,"TEXT:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the (optional) lines up to the line with `"TEXT:`, but wrap that in a capture group. `re.split` will then reproduce what is in that capture group as separate entries in the returned list of chunks. You can then pair up these chunks to get the final split:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(?m)^((?:ID NUMBER:\n)?(?:XSOR-\d+"\n)?\d+,\d*,"TEXT:\n)')

s = """
Performed by:

ID NUMBER:
XSOR-160491"
15632894,136259874,"TEXT:
Name: John    Age:80

XSOR-160491"
78452156,784569851,"TEXT:
Name: Sally    Age:31

ID NUMBER:
01236589,489456156878,"TEXT:
Name: Suraj    Age:56

00123795,,"TEXT:
Name: Shiloh    Age:12
"""

it = iter(regex.split(s))
# Pair the "delimiter" chunks with the successor chunks:
result = [next(it)] + [match + next(it) for match in it]

print("----\n".join(result))
```

The output of this code is:

```
Performed by:

----
ID NUMBER:
XSOR-160491"
15632894,136259874,"TEXT:
Name: John    Age:80

----
XSOR-160491"
78452156,784569851,"TEXT:
Name: Sally    Age:31

----
ID NUMBER:
01236589,489456156878,"TEXT:
Name: Suraj    Age:56

----
00123795,,"TEXT:
Name: Shiloh    Age:12
```

The regular expression is quite strict, so if you have some more variation in the lines that start a block, you'll have to relax the regex accordingly.

### Explanation of regex

- `(?m)` is the *multiline* flag (for the whole regex) that indicates that `^`  (and `$`) match line-ends instead of text-ends.
- `^` requires the match to start at the beginning of a line
- `(?:   )?` makes a part optional without creating a so-called capture group for it.
- `(?:ID NUMBER:\n)?` allows for this optional, literal line
- `(?:XSOR-\d+"\n)?` allows for this optional line that has some digits (`\d+`)
- `\d+,\d*,"TEXT:\n'` requires a line with two numbers, of which the second is optional.
- `(   )`: this wraps around the whole match, and is the only capture group in the regex. `re.split` will reproduce what is captured inside those parentheses as a separate chunk in the returned list.

Comment: Thank you! Marked it as solved, it worked perfectly. Any resources you recommend for regex? And do you mind explaining the regex expression?

Comment: I added a section to my answer about this.